# sharing object across different classes

Tags: java, jdbc

I need some "design" advise. I have static JDBC objects and my "main entry class" which are shared among other classes.

My `MainClass` looks like this:

```
public static Jdbc db1;
public static Jdbc db2;

connectDb(makeDirectConnection) // depending on runtime passed argument

public static connectDb(boolean makeDirectConnection) {
if(makeDirectConnection) // use direct connection
    db1 = JdbcFactory.getInstance("db/config/main/db1.properties");
    db2 = JdbcFactory.getInstance("db/config/main/db2.properties");
} else { // connect using via SSH tunnel (different host and port)
    db1 = JdbcFactory.getInstance("db/config/tunnel/db1.properties");
    db2 = JdbcFactory.getInstance("db/config/tunnel/db2.properties");
}
```

`JdbcFactory` maintains `Map` of instances.

It kinda works ok, but if I want to make unit test for classes where `db1` or `db2` is being used I get null pointer exception if from unit test I don't do `MainClass.dbConnect()`

Make thing worse - from test classes I need even one more different DB setup, so from `Test.class` I do:

```
Main.db1 = JdbcFactory.getInstance("db/config/test/db1.properties");
```

All together it's messy and I don't like. Isn't there some nicer approach how to share `db1` and `db2`?

Also `boolean makeDirectConnection` which is defined from java run argument stops me from using `final` `db1` and `db2`. Any advice how to workaround this? (It depends on environment where program is executed - but I don't want to make it dependable on hostname or some other OS thing.

Comment: You could use an immutable (i.e. no mutator methods like setters) object that contains those connections. That object could be created by a factory object or method which can be called by your main class or your test. Then you pass that object around as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are need to set the default instance diffrently for testing and deployment. So create a [property file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) which mentiones that which file should be used to create default instance for `db1` and `db2`.

To remove the need of calling `MainClass.dbConnect()` from your unit test code, just create a static block and here initlize `db1` and `db2` with default. e.g. If property file is `defaultDB.properties` and having following content:

```
DB1=db/config/test/db1.properties
DB2=db/config/test/db2.properties
```

then use following:

```
static private Properties prop;
static {
    prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("defaultDB.properties"));
    db1 = JdbcFactory.getInstance(prop.getProperty("DB1"));
    db2 = JdbcFactory.getInstance(prop.getProperty("DB2"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not provide a boolean as the jvm argument to differ between your two (or three) cases. Instead i would provide the db urls via paramter. In that case you can also call your method within your test with the "test-db.properties".